# I'm having z-index and centering issues with a horizontal sub menu built in css [wordpress]

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

### The Code: http://jsfiddle.net/TwCLr/

If you'd like to see what I'm trying to accomplish, skip to the link at the bottom of this post.

I'm having positioning issues as well as z-index problems in a horizontal sub-menu design.

I imagine this whole process could be handled through jquery (might even be necessary). I'd be happy to hear suggestions on that if anyone has a script that will work here.

I should also mention that the html for the menu is generated with wordpress. If I wanted to change that portion, I would need to rewrite the function that calls for the menus.

### functions.php

```
function conceptx_setup() {
register_nav_menu( 'primary', __( 'Primary Menu', 'conceptx' ) );}
add_theme_support( 'menus' );
```

### nav html

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(); ?>
```

It would be ideal if there was a solution here that didn't require that the html portion to be changed. I've written out the wordpress generated structure in the jsfiddle link at the top of the post.

---

And a quick and dirty gif of how it's supposed to function: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cztL6.gif

---

If anyone can help, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this: [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TwCLr/1/)

**Added/Changed CSS**

```
.menu .menu-item:hover .sub-menu {
    top: 82px;
}

.menu .menu-item .sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 16px;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    transition: all .5s;
}

.menu .menu-item .sub-menu .menu-item a {
    opacity: 1 /* just remove opacity: 0*/
}
```

#### EDIT: Centered the menu

[**Fiddle Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/TwCLr/6/)

[**Full-screen here**](http://jsfiddle.net/TwCLr/6/show)

Comment: Thanks a million kind stranger -- I'd up vote you post, but I haven't reached the minimum 'reputation' count yet...

I don't suppose you know how to center align the sub menu to the browser view-port rather than floating left in the parent container?

Comment: [**This**](http://jsfiddle.net/TwCLr/3/) ([**full-screen**](http://jsfiddle.net/TwCLr/3/show)) is probably not what you are looking for but still. I had to change `display` of `.sub-menu` and its `li` to `inline-block` to get correct width. Then it was just 2 line `jQuery`. Its in center now but not easily clickable.

Comment: You should probably use [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/TwCLr/4/) instead of the version in my original answer.

Comment: Found a way to do it. Its really bad `jQuery` but it does the trick.
See it here: [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/TwCLr/6/). [**Fullscreen**](http://jsfiddle.net/TwCLr/6/show)

Comment: This is perfect! I'm sure others searching for a solution to a problem like this will be happy to come across your post. You really got me out of a bind with this bit of code. Don't stop being awesome :)

Comment: Thank you for your kind words `^_^`. You should remove `box-shadow` from `.sub-menu`. It really looks weird with that.